# How to fix GitHub profile conflicts?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, git-config

The global profile on my terminal was 0xminer11 and its committed using the same profile and I want to use the same profile to push the code as well. but while pushing, it was taking on a different profile.

you can see my logs.

```
naveenarali@NaveenAralis-MacBook-Air gasless-Txs. % git config --global user.name 
0xminer11
naveenarali@NaveenAralis-MacBook-Air gasless-Txs. % git push origin dev
remote: Permission to 0xminer11/gasless-Txs..git denied to cclchd-naveenkumar.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/0xminer11/gasless-Txs..git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

So is there any solution or suggestions to maintain these conflicts?.

I globally configured my GitHub account username and email. but still am facing the same issue.

Comment: `user.name` in your git config is only used for annotating commits. It has nothing to do with authentication or permissions with github.

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check your [git credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials), which might have cached the wrong credentials for `github.com` accessed with HTTPS.

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git credential-xxx get
```

(Replace `xxx` with the value of `git config --global credential.helper`)

If you have multiple accounts accessing GitHub, it is better to include the GitHub user account name (which, as commented, as nothing to do with `git config user.name`) in the remote URL

```bash
cd /path/to/local/repository
git remote set-url origin https://0xminer11@github.com/0xminer11/myRepo
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then a `git push` should trigger a popup asking for your GitHub `0xminer11` [account token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) ([not password](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-12-git-password-authentication-is-shutting-down/))

Comment: @Naveen-Arali Great! How did you fix the issue? Was adding the right user in the URL enough?

Comment: i just configured origin url. as you shown and its worked..

Comment: @Naveen-Arali Excellent. That way, you know Git will use the right user account to fetch its associated credentials.